# How to file filter using wscript.shell when populating with Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(files)

Tags: excel, vba, wscript.shell

Cannot determine the correct parameter to file filter with recursive wscript.shell.

Have tried to filter in Application.FileDialog, failed.
Have tried to include .txt extension following dir, failed, still retrieves all files in the recursive directories.

```
Sub test()
    Rows("5:" & Rows.Count).ClearContents
    Dim fileSpec As String, files As Variant
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        If .Show = -1 Then
            Folder = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
    fileSpec = Folder
    Debug.Print Folder
    ' How to file filter to select only files with a specific *.dbf extension?
    ' How to get the path without the file name and place into another column?
    files = Split(CreateObject("wscript.shell").exec("cmd /c dir " & Chr(34) & fileSpec & Chr(34) & " /b/s ").stdout.readall, vbCrLf)
    ActiveSheet.Range("C5").Resize(UBound(files)).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(files)
End Sub
```

Comment: added `Folder As String` I do not see how this would impact the file filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a `Dim` statement to `folder` so there was no error on that. Then I added `*.TXT` to your WSript code. This now only returns Text Files.

```
Sub test()
    Rows("5:" & Rows.Count).ClearContents
    Dim fileSpec As String
    Dim files As Variant
    Dim folder As Variant

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        If .Show = -1 Then
            folder = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
    fileSpec = folder
    Debug.Print folder
    ' How to file filter to select only files with a specific *.dbf extension?
    ' How to get the path without the file name and place into another column?
    files = Split(CreateObject("wscript.shell").exec("cmd /c dir " & Chr(34) _
            & fileSpec & "\*.txt" & Chr(34) & " /b/s ").StdOut.ReadAll, vbCrLf)
    ActiveSheet.Range("C5").Resize(UBound(files)).Value = _
            Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(files)
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, thank you, works perfectly.  Is it possible to also transpose the path into a different column?

Comment: Sure. Just change the "C5" Range specification to the column you would like.

Comment: Thank you, I hoped to have the ability to accomplish two transposes, the second with the path.